# Using calculus to show this inequality

Tags: calculus

Use the function $f(x) = x - e*ln(x)$ and calculus techniques to show that $e^π > π^e$

This was in my exam a few days ago, I made no progress in the exam on it. Any hint or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that

$$e^π > π^e \iff \ln (e^π) >\ln( π^e)\iff f(\pi)=π -e\ln π >0$$

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x)=1-\frac e x>0$ if $x >e$ and $<0$ if $x <e$. Thus $f$ is decreasing in $(0,e)$ and increasing in $(e,\infty)$. Since $f(e)=0$ it follows that $f(x) >0$ for all $x \neq e$. In particular $f(\pi) >0$ and this gives the required inequality.

Answer (score 0):

gimusi's answer explains the relevance of $f(x)$ to showing $e^{\pi}>\pi^e$.

Using that $f'(x)=1-\frac ex$, we easily see:

$$f'(x)=0 \iff x=e$$
$$f'(x)>0\iff x>e$$
$$f'(x)<0\iff x<e, x\ne 0$$

Since it only has one turning point, and we can verify that $f(e)=0$, we see that $f(x)\ge 0$